# How to implement Vuex store in cordova as secure storage

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, vuex

I wanted to know if someone implemented an apache cordova and vuex plugin, to save the store in the phone's secure storage, and how they did it. Thank you!!

Comment: This is an article on it: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/cordova/storage/storage.html